# Why Rails provides less number of time zones support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

There are more than 230 time zones in the world.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country

But Rails supports only 142 time zones.

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.count
=> 142
```

1.Does it means Rails time zone support is limited?

2.Is there any specific reason to skip the remaining time zones?

Thank you folks.

Comment: Some countries share time zones. There are only [139 named time zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Comment: Your are correct.I was confirmed this with time the zone selection GUI in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `rake time:zones:all` ?

1. No, Rails time zones support is not limited. You have all the zones from UTC -11:00 to UTC +13:00.
2. See (1.). There are no skipped time zones in Rails.

Comment: I have used rake:zones:all and analyzed the result.It lists only 142 time zones.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There are only 24 hours in a day - how many time zones do you *need*?!